# Customising Twitter Embedded Timeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am wondering to what extent I can customise the Embedded Timeline. I was reading the documentation but couldn't find all the answers - maybe I was looking at the wrong place.

What I am trying to achieve is - I want to show only a SINGLE tweet to start with and upon clicking Load More, I'd like to display rest of the tweets. Is it possible to do this?

When I am setting up the Embedded Timeline in the Widgets Configuration, I cannot see the Load More button in the Preview area. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

With the Embedded Timeline widget you can only customise the following:

- Theme
- Link color
- Width
- Height
- Chrome (Header/Footer/Scrollbar/Borders/Transparency)
- Border color
- Language
- Tweet limit
- Web Intent Related Users
- ARIA politeness

So to show a single tweet - you'd need to set the tweet limit to 1 using the `data-tweet-limit` attribute e.g.

`a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" data-widget-id="YOUR-WIDGET-ID-HERE" data-tweet-limit="1" lang="EN">Tweets by @twitterapi`

You cannot achieve the Load More functionality you are referring to with this widget alone.

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#customization